# Is there any way to access PostgreSQL SQLSTATE codes in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to get the error code in a PostgreSQL exception from SQLAlchemy.

Is there a way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. It's available on the `orig.pgcode` member.

e.g.

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

try:
   exec_database_script(...)
except sa.exc.IntegrityError as e:
   pgcode = int(e.orig.pgcode)

   if pgcode == 23514:
      print("Check constraint violation!")
```